# Ifstream is failing to load a file and it won't open

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, nintendo-ds

Some of this code may seem foreign to you since I make 3ds homebrew programs for fun but it's essentially the same but with extra lines of code you can put in. I'm trying to read a file called about.txt in a separate folder. I made it work when I put it in the same folder but i lost that file and then my partner said he wanted it in `Scratch3ds-master\assets\english\text` and not in `Scratch3ds-master\source` I keep getting the error I coded in. I'm new to stack-overflow so this might be too much code but well here's the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Initialize the services
    gfxInitDefault();
    consoleInit(GFX_TOP, NULL);

    int version_major;
    int version_minor;
    int version_patch;

    version_major = 0;
    version_minor = 0;
    version_patch = 2;




    printf("This is the placeholder for Scratch3ds\n\n");

    std::ifstream about_file;
    about_file.open("../assets/english/text/about.txt");


    if (about_file.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "file has failed to load\n";
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: You are opening the file using a *relative* path, so the most likely culprit is the calling process's *current working directory* is not what you are expecting it to be. Always use *absolute* paths when opening files. If the location of the file is relative to the location of the EXE file, dynamically retrieve the absolute path to the EXE first, strip off the filename, ans append the relative path.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how would i go about doing this when i wont know the exact position of the file? since it's on the 3ds (im pretty sure the drive is called 0:/ but that causes an error in the assembler) i don't know the entire path

Comment: "*how would i go about doing this when i wont know the exact position of the file?*" - like I said before, query the full path of the current process at runtime, and then modify it as needed. I'm sure the 3DS has some API you can use for that. Or, since the 3DS is a fairly closed system, the folder path is likely fixed so just hard-code it.

Comment: Are you loading this from a SD card? Where is the file on the SD card?

Answer (score -1):

Chance are that you're using devkitpro packages. And chances are that the devkitpro team provide an equivalent of the NDS 'ARGV protocol' for 3DS programming. In which case, if you use

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

you should have the full path to your executable in `argv[0]` if `argc` is non-zero.

https://devkitpro.org/wiki/Homebrew_Menu might help.

Your program has no a priori knowledge of what sort of arguments `main()` should receive, and in your question, you're using a main function that receives no argument at all.

Established standard for C/C++ programming is that `main()` will receive an array of constant C strings (typically named `argv` for **arg**uments **v**alues) and the number of valid entries in that array (typically named `argc` for **c**ount). If you replace your original code with

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   // Initialize the services
   // ... more code follows
```

then you're able to tell whether you received argument by testing `argc > 0` and you'll be able to get these arguments values with `argv[i]`.

With homebrew development, it is unlikely that you can pass arguments such as `--force` or `--directory=/boot` as on typical command-line tools, but there is one thing that is still useful: the very first entry in `argv` is supposed to be a full path for the running program. so you're welcome to try

```
std::cerr << ((argc > 0) ? argv[0] : "<no arguments>");
```

and see what you get.

Comment: can you elaborate how to use that line of code im not that experienced

Comment: I presumed you were familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point. See the updated answer.